# Add Ponytails in avatar

Tags: bezier-curves

I don't use blender so much and I need help.
I would like to create a ponytail like the image in the link, I don't know how to create the curve (shape) in the image. Can you help me?
I appreciate also YouTube tutorial.
Thanks!

https://cgcookie.com/posts/how-to-model-hair-in-blender

Comment: Please add an image to your question so that we don't have to go to an external site to see what you're talking about. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Asking for links to resources about X is considered off topic here, asking directly about X is encouraged though. If you can rephrase your question to focus on the specific difficulties you are encountering, rather that point you to some site, please [edit] your post so it can be reopened. As it stands it is not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create hair, a method is to create a curve, and under *Object Data > Geometry*, click on *Object*, and choose your *Object* and your *Taper object*, which are 2 other curves that you need to edit the way you want to define the section profile and the length profile:

[image]